# Terraform: Deploying a Docker Compose app on EKS/ECS

Tags: docker-compose, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, apache-superset

### TL;DR

I use an open-source server application **running on Docker Compose**. It has a few services, including PostgreSQL DB and Redis.

**How can I best deploy this application to AWS in full IaC with Terraform?**

### Solutions so far

#### 1. AWS `ecs-cli`

[`ecs-cli`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI.html) now [supports](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-ecs-cli-supports-docker-compose-version-3/) sending `docker compose` configs in Amazon ECS.

However, I do not think it could be integrated with the Terraform workflow (which is maybe not a big fuss). What I know for sure is that `ecs-cli` is **not supported in CloudFormation**, as per [this issue](https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation/issues/17), still open at this time. So I assume it cannot easily be added to Terraform either.

#### 2. The hard EKS way

- Take your `docker-compose.yml` file, translate it to `kubectl` YAML.
- (Prepare to doing so every time the package upgrades).
- Deploy using Terraform's + EKS APIs (minimal [example](https://github.com/foxutech/nodejs-k8s-aws)).

But that is not fully IaC yet. And you have to retranslate your config each time the docker-compose changes in the source repository. And it sounds like a lot of work.

#### 3. Using a Helm chart

- Write a Helm chart for the application.
- Run Terraform to start a cluster.
- Still run Terraform with a `helm` [provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/helm/index.html) to install the application with Helm on the cluster.

#### 4. [Not OK] k8s Kompose

I read [Kompose](https://kompose.io/) can automagically translate a Docker Compose configuration to a k8s configuration, but they don't appear to be ported on AWS, not to talk about Terraform.

#### 5. [Not OK] The dirty AMI solution

- Build a custom EC2 AMI with Packer.
- Using Terraform, set up the DB, Redis and all permissions / network / etc.
- Start an EC2 instance with the custom AMI.
- The AMI contains (customized) application code, especially the `docker-compose.yml`. And the Docker images.
- The AMI starts a Docker Compose `systemctl` service.

That would kind of hurt: long builds, difficult monitoring, no scaling.

### Side notes

- I mentioned I need **full IaC**. What I mean by it is:

  1. The written config (and it only) on `master` tells you what is deployed.
  2. The deploy will complete without my team having to run any other command. It basically works either on CI/CD or on single-push'n'go.
  3. Monitoring and alerting are easily configured in the IaC.
- I wish to replace some services with AWS components (namely, the PostgreSQL service by an RDS, and the Redis service with an ElastiCache).
- The application *happens* to be [Apache Superset](https://github.com/apache/superset). However I am also wondering what is considered the best general approach to this Docker Compose problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Wait and See

Who knows, [`ecs-cli-v2`](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli-v2) might be better integrated with CloudFormation and/or Terraform.

#### 2. Use a Helm chart

As mentioned in the question. Probably the best solution, albeit requiring a (little) effort to parametrize Helm.

See also: [Getting started with Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/).

#### 3. Docker Swarm + CloudFormation + Terraform

Docker Swarm now [accepts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/) inputs from a `docker-compose.yml` file. The template can be found and configured [here](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-aws?tab=resources). Once configured, it may be integrated to a Terraform infrastructure.

This (3-year old) [tutorial](https://stelligent.com/2017/02/21/docker-swarm-mode-on-aws/) explains how to use Docker Swarm mode on AWS.

To launch the container, if necessary (not fully investigated, feedback is welcome), you could use Terraform's [`local-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html). This way you can SSH into the master node and run `docker stack deploy` and other similar commands, while still having all written down in IaC style.

Comment: thanks for this! I tried to use https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/ just to hit a roadblock (can't deploy to a region of your choice)

Comment: Conversion of `docker-compose.yml` to a helm chart can be automated using the `kompose` tool as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445478/converting-docker-compose-to-a-helm-chart/63944634#63944634)